# Debugging in Android Webkit: unhelpful exception

Tags: javascript, debugging, android-browser, mobile-webkit

I'm debugging a web app on an Android phone running webkit (browser listed as "Webkit 3.1"). I'm using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) to view the console, where I'm logging debug information.

The log messages from Android webkit are very different than in other browsers -- instead of being the normal output, most read:

```
[ Exception: TypeError: Result of expression 'Object.getOwnPropertyNames' [undefined] is not a function. ]
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this message, or how to proceed debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the expression in question and try to run it with a valid argument in the console: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)`. For future reference, compare the [useragent](http://www.useragentstring.com/Safari3.1.2_id_17215.php) to the Webkit version in which [getOwnPropertyNames](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/01/15/ecmascript-5-and-webkitjavascriptcore/) was implemented.